# how to compare lists of structures using iterator?

Tags: c++, list, struct, stl

I have a structure.

```
struct Vertex
{
       list<Vertex> adj;
       unsigned short distance; // zero or infinity
       bool known;

};
```

I want to compare distance in the elements of list type vertex; any idea???

```
Vertex findMin(list<Vertex> &adj)
{
       Vertex min;
       for(list<Vertex>::iterator it = adj.begin(); it != adj.end(); it++){
                 // if(it->distance < (adj.next())->distance){

                  //}

       return min;
}
```

I am using this function to return min vertex on the basis of distance property

Comment: Please provide example or clarify your question

Comment: If your `list` is `std::list`, your code will cause *undefined behaviour*. You can't instantiate std library containers with incomplete types.

Comment: You can simplify this question: given a `list<Vertex>`, return the element with the minimum `distance`. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vertex findMin(const list<Vertex> &adj)
{
  if(adj.empty())
    throw(0); // cannot find minimum of an empty list;

  list<Vertex>::const_iterator bestVertex = adj.begin();
  unsigned short minDistance = bestVertex->distance;

  for(list<Vertex>::const_iterator itr=adj.begin(); itr!=adj.end(); ++itr)
    if(itr->distance < minDistance)
      {
        bestVertex = itr;
        minDistance = bestVertex->distance;
      }

  return *bestVertex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `std::min_element` algorithm.  Here is pre-C++11 code:

```
bool isDistanceLess(const Vertex& v1, const Vertex& v2)
{  return v1.distance < v2.distance; }

Vertex findMin(const std::list<Vertex>& adj)
{ return *std::min_element(adj.begin(), adj.end(), isDistanceLess); }
```

Here is the C++11 version:

```
Vertex findMin(const std::list<Vertex>& adj)
{ return *std::min_element(adj.begin(), adj.end(), [](const Vertex& v1, const Vertex& v2) { return v1.distance < v2.distance; })); }
```